# UISplitViewControlller master controller hiding

Tags: rotation, uisplitviewcontroller, ios6

I am porting an app to iOS 6 and I found a solution I had deviced to trigger on and off the showing of the master view controller in a split view controller no longer works on iOS 6.

This is the piece of code I employed to trigger the action that on iOS6 just works if the device gets rotated:

```
- (void)hideMaster:(BOOL)hide {

[self clearOverlay];

UISplitViewController* spv = appDelegate.splitViewController;

NSLog(@"hidemaster: I do %@show the master", (hide?@"not ":@""));

self.hiddenMaster= hide;

NSLog(@"delegate=%@", spv.delegate);

[spv.view setNeedsLayout];
spv.delegate=nil;

spv.delegate=self;

}

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc shouldHideViewController: (UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

NSLog(@"Spv: I do %@show the master", (self.hiddenMaster?@"not ":@""));

return self.hiddenMaster;
}
```

How do I force the shouldHideViewController callback to be triggered wthout the user rotating the device?

Thanks,
Fabrizio Bartolomucci

Comment: I have same problem, you got the solution of that? please share here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got rid of it by following the Apple documentation suggesting to only open it according to the user's directions. Now I restored it just for a secondary panel the user actually manually opens and than on the iPhone version is managed by an unwinding segue.

Answer (score 5):

Easier than expected: I put the [spv.view setNeedsLayout]; soon after calling your function and it perfectly does the job.
That is the full code for the benefit of other users:

```
- (void)hideMaster:(BOOL)hide {
   NSLog(@"hide-unhide master");
   UISplitViewController* spv = appDelegate.splitViewController;
   spv.delegate=self;
   self.hiddenMaster= hide;
   [spv willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
   [spv.view setNeedsLayout];
}

- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
   NSLog(@"Spv: I do %@ show the master", (self.hiddenMaster?@"not ":@""));
   return self.hiddenMaster;  
}
```

Comment: I do not know if the two things are connected or not, but the table in the master view controller shows empty cells yet in the right number when executed on the iPad, while it shows everything correctly when executed on the simulator. What could it be? I also tried deleting and reinstalling the app on the iPad to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
spv.delegate=nil;
spv.delegate=self;
```

you need to do

```
[spv willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation duration:0];
```

and you will be happy.

Comment: Quite so, thanks. The - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation callback is actually called following your advice. Yet nothing happens until the device is rotated even if that callback returns NO. I suspect I need a  [spv.view setNeedsLayout] somewhere, but I have no cue where to put it as I think it should happen after the exit from the callback.

Answer (score 0):

No way to solve this issue. Even Apple displayed a white flag. I changed the architecture to have all views as popups and got rid of the split view controller altogether. I could not delay the introduction of auto layout any longer.